# Can I automatically add photos and videos that conform to certain conditions to a shared album in Google Photos?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-photos, if-this-then-that

The conditions that I'm talking about would be something like:

```
photoOrVideo.cameraName == "Apple iPhone X" && photoOrVideo.contains("My friend")
```

Google Photos is already set up to be able to recognize my friend. And I can see in the photo details that it knows when it was taken by my iPhone, because then it shows this:

[image: Photo details]

The reason I care about this condition is because my iPhone also syncs photos with Google that I receive from WhatsApp. And it wouldn't make sense to me, if she sends me a photo from herself on WhatsApp, that that photo would then also be added to the album that I'm sharing with her. I really only want to add photos that were taken by my iPhone.

It would be so great if I can configure Google or otherwise create some kind of external script that would automatically add those photos and videos to the album that I shared with her.

Is this possible? I can imagine that it may not be possible with just a setting in Google Photos, but then it may be possible using ITTT or Google Scripts. I'm not familiar enough with ITTT or Google Scripts to know how to do it in either of those though. I'd love some help on this.